# Perl - parse xml stored as string in a variable

Tags: xml, perl

I have done a lot of searches on google, but is there a way to parse and get values similar to extracting values from a file, if the XML is contained in the string.

Following is a sample script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml  = "<family><id>25502</id><father><id>1</id></father><mother><id>2</id></mother><son><id>2</id></son></family>";

my $id = $xml->getElementsByTagName("id")->item(0)->getFirstChild->getData;

print $id;
```

In this example, I could not print the ID. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: And you didn't think it was worthwhile to mention that you're receiving an error message when you try this? **Can't call method "getElementsByTagName" without a package or object reference**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how objects and XML parsing work. You can't just use a module and suddenly expect it to have an effect on all variables in your program.

If you read the documentation for [XML::LibXML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod) it will show you how to parse your XML string into a document object which you can then query using various methods.

You will want code like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '<family> ... </family>';

my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $doc = $xml_parser->parse_string($xml);
```

You now have a XML document variable (in `$doc`) that you can call the XML::LibXML methods on.

Answer (score 3):

You code will work with the fix describe by **Dave Cross**, but it can be made much more concise

I recommend something like this. Note that, when called in list context, `getChildrenByTagName` returns a list of `XML::LibXML::Node` objects instead of one `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object. The same applies to any method that returns a list of nodes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<__END_XML__;
<family>
    <id>25502</id> 
    <father>
        <id>1</id>
    </father>
    <mother>
        <id>2</id>
    </mother>
    <son>
        <id>2</id>
    </son>
</family>
__END_XML__

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );

my ($family_id) = $doc->documentElement->getChildrenByTagName('id');

say $family_id->textContent;
```

#### output

```
25502
```

And if you are expecting to do much work with XML then you should familiarise yourself with XPath. With its help the above assignment could be written as

```
my ($family_id) = $doc->findnodes('/family/id');
```